# TFS 2017 Open a Work Item from Angular App

Tags: angular, authentication, tfs

I built a TFS 2017 extension that leverages Angular Framework. The extension has a table with a column for Work Item ID. On clicking that ID, the requirement is to open the Work Item.

The click event passes the work item ID to an Angular component method. That method that has the following window.open("http://hostname:8080/tfs/collection/project/_workitems?_a=edit&id=" + id, "_blank");

This opens up a new window but I get a "TFS400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required." error. If I take the same URL and paste in another browser, I'm able to access the work item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, looks like your other browser cached your personal authentication and then it works and opens the url succeed.

> TFS400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client
>   authentication required.

For this kind of error, if you are using PAT token to handle the authentication. Since you are using PAT **with on-premise TFS server**, make sure you already **turned off Basic Authentication** on server. Otherwise you will get an returned error.

> We recommend you keep IIS Basic Authentication turned off at all times
>   when using Azure DevOps Server. Only if necessary should you enable
>   IIS Basic Authentication. When IIS Basic Authentication is enabled on
>   your windows machine, it prevents you from using personal access
>   tokens (PATs) as an authentication mechanism.
>
> *[Source link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops)*

If this not work, check if you are behind a proxy. Will the proxy cause the issue? Try to bypass the proxy when use in your original browser.

Also try to clear browser cache, which may do the trick. Besides, you could also collect and analysis fiddler logs during your open work item action. This kind of logs should help for troubleshooting.